# Question on $\mathbb C^{n \times n}$-valued integrability in the literature

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading through *Volterra Integral and Functional Equations* by *Gripenberg, Londen & Staffans*. Let $p, q \in [1,\infty]$ and further $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$. I have the following question from their definition of a norm $\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert \cdot
    \right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert_{L^{p}(\mathbb R)}$ for a given measurable function $K:\mathbb R^{2}\to \mathbb C^{n \times n}$, where the norm is defined as follows on page $227$,

$$\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert K
    \right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert_{L^{p}(\mathbb R)}=\sup_{\substack{\lvert\lvert g\rvert\rvert_{L^{q}(\mathbb R,\mathbb C)}\leq 1 \\ \lvert \lvert f\rvert\rvert_{L^{p}(\mathbb R, \mathbb C)}\leq 1 }}\int_{\mathbb R} \int_{\mathbb R} \lvert g(t)K(t,s)f(s)\rvert ds dt, $$

where $f,g$ are scalar functions of the form $f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb C$, i.e. they are scalar. In this case we say that $K$ is of type $[L^{p}, \mathbb R,\mathbb C^{n \times n}]$.

My question: There are no further details given on the norm $\lvert \cdot \rvert$ within the integral. The way I interpret it would be
$$\lvert \cdot \rvert: \mathbb C^{n^{2}}\to \mathbb R,\; x \mapsto \sum\limits_{i\in \{1,..,n^{2}\}}\lvert x_{i}\rvert, $$

so we would be testing integrability of the individual functions $$ g(t)K_{ij}(t,s)f(s),$$

for all $(i,j)\in [1,...,n]^{2}$.

Is my interpretation of the norm  $\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert K
    \right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert_{L^{p}(\mathbb R)}$ that is defined in *Volterra Integral and Functional Equations* correct? Or, does it even matter what norm we endow $\mathbb C^{n \times n}$ with, since they are all equivalent on finite-dimensional spaces?

**Additional comment**: Surely by this logic if $K$ is of type $[L^{p}, \mathbb R,\mathbb C^{n \times n}]$, then $K$ is also of type $[L^{q}, \mathbb R,\mathbb C^{n \times n}]$ where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$?

Comment: Até you sure $f$ and $g$ are scalar valued?  I suspect they might take values in $\mathbb C^n$.

Comment: @Ruy That was my initial thought too but it specifically states that $f,g$ are scalar functions